# Why do car keys have longer range when held next to your head?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas, radio

I first saw this on Top Gear, and assumed it was a load of rubbish, but today I tried it out and it actually works, if you walk away from the car continuously unlocking/locking it until it stops, and go a bit further away so that the car will not un/lock. Then out the car keys next to your head and point them directly at the car it will un/lock.

How does your head/brain/etc increase the range of the keys? And why does it only work next to your head if you point the keys directly at the car, when you do not have to point towards the car when in normal range?

Comment: Probably has more to do with the height at which you hold the keys rather than their proximity to your head.

Comment: @dbrane, I thought of this too when I was doing and so held it up at the height my head was and ducked. But afterwards I can see no reason why the height would affect it, both had clear lines of sight. As I understand it range should be a spherical bubble, so increase the height vertically on a spot outside of this "bubble" should increase the distance from the car, making the car further out of range

Comment: This explains it [Brain Increase in Car Key Range](http://www.certifiedpsychics.com/) Of course, in this context "certified" may have other meanings.

Comment: @Gordon: ??? what does that have to with the question, I'm asking physically, not psychically

Comment: More seriously, 1. increase in height. 2. If not that, the head/body acting as an amplifying antenna.

Comment: @Jonathan---obviously a joke. I am finding that this site needs to take itself less seriously.

Comment: @Gordon: Right sorry, a bit obvious now thinking properly :)

Comment: Assuming its really true, and not an effect of pointing versus not pointing or height. It might be an effect of having the transmitter near to a conductive (reflecting) surface. I.E. some of the EM radiation emitted in the direction of your head is reflected back towards the car. Presumably holding it close to your chest should work as well or better if this explanation is true.

Comment: try holding it a half-wavelength from your head (reinforcing reflection) and compare that to holding it a quarter-wavelength (interfering reflection). Any difference?

Comment: @JustJeff: microwave wavelengths are of the order of centimeters.

Comment: RF key fobs are typically only somewhere around 300 to 500MHz, for which the wavelength is 1m down to 60cm. Even at 2.45GHz, common for lots of things but not afaik, key fobs, wavelength is ~ 12cm.

Answer (score 14):

It works with a lot of body parts. It will work with a piece of 
wire too. This keys work at about 433 Mhz, a resonant Lamda/4 antenna 
is about 18 cm. Obviously the whole key is shorter, the antanna 
is not tuned for maximum power transmission. By bringing the key 
close to some conductive material, the power transmitted increases.

[A very recondite answer is found here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoDXyfAUBQc).

Comment: I have taken one of these apart before.  The antenna was a copper trace running in a spiral around the outside of the PCB.  I think it would be foolish if the engineers didn't design the antenna correctly, so that is probably fine.  Also, I am very confused about the "pointing the key" comments people are making.  I don't think it emits a roughly focussed 'beam' in any direction.  So while I don't doubt people are seeing increased range, some of the details seem quite sketchy and anecdotal instead of systematic tests.

Comment: A similar effect can also be observed if you have a cheap AM radio with a random wire antenna, or a low-quality TV antenna (before the switch to digital signals). By moving your body (a large conductor) closer and further away from the antenna (staying within about half meter or so), you can easily affect the reception quality.

Comment: @Willie, try the link in my answer :=)

Comment: FM reception increases considerably when the antennae is help in hands..

Answer (score 1):

It actually does increase the range. Here is the 'experiment' I performed once.

Walk away from the car and find the range at which the key fails to work. Walk away another 5 feet. Turn and put the key against your chest, so that it points towards the car through your body. It worked!! I did some more testing. Apparently the range increases by about ten feet if the key is used through the body.

I have no idea why.